# Convert cooldown timer in discord.py into hrs:min:sec format

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a bot made using discord.py. I added a suggest command and added cooldown to it. After that I added this code:

```
@suggest.error
async def suggest_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        msg = 'You are too fast! Please try again in {:.2f}s'.format(error.retry_after)
        await ctx.send(msg)
    else:
        raise error
```

Now, it shows the time in seconds, how do I make it show in hr:min:sec format?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the datetime module

```py
import datetime

remaining_time = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(error.retry_after)))
```

Comment: @suggest.error
async def suggest_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        remaining_time = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds = int(error.retry_after)))
  msg = 'You are too fast! Please try again in' + remaining_time
        await ctx.send(msg)
    else:
        raise error

I wrote this and I am still getting various errors..

Btw is there a way to convert this directly:
@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, type = commands.BucketType.default)

Answer (score 0):

```
def hms_from_secs(seconds: int) -> str:
    seconds = int(seconds)
    hours = seconds // 3600
    minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
    seconds = seconds % 60
    return f"{hours:02} hour(s) {minutes:02} minute(s)"
```

Comment: add some explanation please